# Error when send reset password

Tags: users, reset, password

I forget my Password in my site, So i go to this link to res

```
http://domain.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword
```

And put my email and send it.

I received an email, But without link to reset my password.

This problem show for all users in my site.

How can fixed this error.

Comment: no no, I say i have problem in reset email message. for any time there are any user need to change pass

Comment: Do you using any plugin for register , login?

Comment: No, I am not using any thing for this

Comment: ok , did you update wp version recently? what is your current wp version?

Comment: yes i update my WordPress to last version

Comment: I think because of that this issue arise. May be some files related forgot password not updated properly.

Comment: I update again and not work yet

Comment: Can you please show me code of reset password? OR please paste code of file "wp-login.php" in your question.

Comment: i don't have code. its form wordpress

Comment: Yes but that function of  reset password works based on code. without checking code I think very difficult to identify issue.

Answer (score 0):

For starters recovering your own access would be good. If email approach fails for you, Codex has [Resetting Your Password](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password) page which gives instructions for several more approaches.

To troubleshoot the issue in general you should start with disabling plugins / using default theme, and likely checking WordPress core files for modification or simply replacing them with clean copy of core.